# Laravel 5 Override Eloquent Save Method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have composite primary keys so Laravel's save() method didn't work. Therefore I need to override the save method. For example, my primary key is a composite key consisting of column_a and column_b. Can you give me example how to override the save method and where I put it?

My Primary Key: column_a, column_b

I've tried the followings:

```
protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
{
    parent::setKeysForSaveQuery($query);
    $query->where('locale', '=', $this->locale);
    return $query;
}
```

I found above code, but it causes 500 Internal Server Error even I call a method that only reads value from database. I have set $primaryKey = 'column_a' and 'locale' (inside where) to column_b. I didn't know what $this->locale refers to?

Here is another way I found, but it failed too

```
protected $secondaryKey = 'column_b';
function newQuery()
{
    $query = parent::newQuery();
    $query->where($this->secondaryKey, '=', $this->type);
    return $query;
}
```

Again, I didn't know what $this->type refers to.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution. In the model, add primaryKey variable and the following function

```
protected $primaryKey = array('column1','column2');

protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query) {
    if (is_array($this->primaryKey)) {
        foreach ($this->primaryKey as $pk) {
            $query->where($pk, '=', $this->original[$pk]);
        }
        return $query;
    }else{
        return parent::setKeysForSaveQuery($query);
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5517#issuecomment-113655441

Answer (score 1):

You can override it. You can put it in your model, or you can put it in a trait and use this trate in multiple models if you want.

The original save() method is [here](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/adfe1ef6c232cfe584750f64b7957d36174bb2d1/Eloquent/Model.php#L832) (line 832), maybe this will help.

Comment: can you give me example? I don't know how to remove id from where clause and add multiple where clause (other columns) to the query

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly do you mean, but as this is new question I'd recommend you to create new answer and describe everything there (with code, what exactly do you want, what you've already tried). I'm sure me or other guys will help you.